# Rails server & bundle failing to run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

So, self confessed rails novice here in need of some help!

Mac OS Mojave 10.14.3

I have come back to keep working on some personal project I'm building in rails and first things first start the rails server with `rails s` command and get the following error/output in terminal:

```
Ignoring bcrypt-3.1.11 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bcrypt --version 3.1.11
Ignoring bindex-0.5.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bindex --version 0.5.0
Ignoring byebug-10.0.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 10.0.2
Ignoring ffi-1.9.23 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.9.23
Ignoring mysql2-0.5.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine mysql2 --version 0.5.2
Ignoring mysql2-0.4.10 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine mysql2 --version 0.4.10
Ignoring nio4r-2.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nio4r --version 2.3.1
Ignoring nio4r-2.3.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nio4r --version 2.3.0
Ignoring nokogiri-1.8.4 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.8.4
Ignoring puma-3.11.4 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine puma --version 3.11.4
Ignoring bcrypt-3.1.11 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bcrypt --version 3.1.11
Ignoring bindex-0.5.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bindex --version 0.5.0
Ignoring byebug-10.0.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 10.0.2
Could not find nokogiri-1.8.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Upon running `bundle install` I get the following output:

```
Ignoring bcrypt-3.1.11 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bcrypt --version 3.1.11
Ignoring bindex-0.5.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bindex --version 0.5.0
Ignoring byebug-10.0.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 10.0.2
Ignoring ffi-1.9.23 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.9.23
Ignoring mysql2-0.5.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine mysql2 --version 0.5.2
Ignoring mysql2-0.4.10 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine mysql2 --version 0.4.10
Ignoring nio4r-2.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nio4r --version 2.3.1
Ignoring nio4r-2.3.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nio4r --version 2.3.0
Ignoring nokogiri-1.8.4 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.8.4
Ignoring puma-3.11.4 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine puma --version 3.11.4
Ignoring websocket-driver-0.6.5 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine websocket-driver --version 0.6.5
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Using rake 12.3.1
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
Using i18n 1.0.1
Using minitest 5.11.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.5
Using activesupport 5.1.6
Using builder 3.2.3
Using erubi 1.7.1
Using mini_portile2 2.3.0
Fetching nokogiri 1.8.2
Installing nokogiri 1.8.2 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/USER/Desktop/Immunophenotyping/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.2/ext/nokogiri
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20190131-45165-drnzr3.rb extconf.rb
--use-system-libraries
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/USER/Desktop/Immunophenotyping/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.2 for
inspection.
Results logged to
/Users/USER/Desktop/Immunophenotyping/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-18/2.3.0/nokogiri-1.8.2/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.8.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.8.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  rails was resolved to 5.1.6, which depends on
    actioncable was resolved to 5.1.6, which depends on
      actionpack was resolved to 5.1.6, which depends on
        actionview was resolved to 5.1.6, which depends on
          rails-dom-testing was resolved to 2.0.3, which depends on
            nokogiri
```

Im at a bit of a loss as to what is wrong as when I last worked on this project I had none of these issues.

Following on and running `gem install nokogiri -v '1.8.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` returns a permissions error.

Sorry for the wall of text, any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Yes, nokogiri failing to compile is probably the most common bundle failure in my experience. What I do is read the generated build log files and google various bits from it. This is enough for most of the cases.

Comment: What do you get when you run `which ruby` from a terminal, and `ruby --version`?

Comment: Ignoring the problems with nokogiri, I'd assume that you updated your OS keeping your data (i.e. the gems) when doing so, which is why their c bindings no longer work. I'd throw away the whole gemset to avoid further problems.

Comment: After running `which ruby` this is where it is located: /usr/bin/ruby
my ruby version is ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]
I know im using RVM for version management and sorry im unsure how to "throw away the whole gemset" and presumably rebuild it

Comment: Your stacktrace suggest that while you may have rvm installed, you are currently not using it. Try the sequence of `rvm get head`, `rvm remove [ruby version]`, `rvm install [ruby version]`, `rvm use [ruby version] --default`

Comment: Thanyou @ulferts weird that it was not using it but after following your steps I updated to the latest version of ruby (2.6.1) then had to follow the steps of installing / updating Nokogiri as @luriG suggested below. Then finally my `bundle update Nokogiri` command works, appears to have reinstalled all gems from my gem file however had to manually reinstall rails gem again and now just have to link up mysql back to my project :D

THANKYOU EVERYONE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nokogiri 1.8.2` has problem building native extensions on latest macOS. You need to upgrade it to latest version (>= 1.10.0) using `bundle update nokogiri`

Comment: Ahh I did wonder if updating macOS would cause any issues... 

I reach a point where I get this message: 

`An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.4.10), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.10' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.`

and after trying to install mysql again as it suggests I get this same permissions error: 

`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.10/CHANGELOG.md`

Comment: Following @ulferts advice above I have removed my previous ruby version and reinstalled the latest version using rvm and then followed your steps to update Nokogiri and now it works :D

As mentioned above, had to manually reinstall the rails gem and will have to re-link mysql to my project but it seems to all be working again! Thankyou!